# What is the difference between cv2.calibrateCamera and cv2.fisheye.calibrate?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

What is the difference between these two functions provided in OpenCV?

Why is there cv2.fisheye.calibrate() function we need?

I tried using cv2.calibrateCamera() for barrel distorted images and I think it is giving me good results, so why would I want to use fisheye.calibrate()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distortion in fisheye lenses is really high. At least in older versions cv2.calibrateCamera() did not fit polynomials with sufficiently high order, so results were poor or the calibration failed altogether. So cv2.fisheye.calibrate() implemented a camera model with higher order polynomials.